# What is better for (stability and security), the myProgram.c call directly malloc, or leave this activity (alloc the memory) to the dll

Tags: c, visual-c++, dll

Looking for security and stability in C code, i created a DLL with Visual Studio C++ 6. My program call a function in this dll to alloc memory

```
(char*)malloc(ARRAY_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
```

and when this need to be free, myProgram.exe call the dll to free this space in memory.

its work fine. But, what is better for (stability and security), the myProgram.c call directly malloc, or leave this activity (alloc the memory) to the dll?

Comment: What keeps the native program from trying to free a pointer allocated by the DLL?

Comment: its a rule i follow, who allocted must be the who release.

Comment: @bruno.karkas, Yes, but it is sort of like a cliff with no railings.  If the dll never allocs/deallocs, then you never have to worry about it.  The downside is that you sometimes have to ask for the size of the thing the dll wants, before allocating it and sending it off.  It's a pain, a real pain, but in some circumstances, it might be safer.